# method in WCF service returns nothing

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got some troubles with method Final(). It should return list of IWeather but returns null when I call it. In debug I stopped on

```
return this.returner;
```

but it was always null and I don't know why because MainMethod() returns "finish" and list "returner" is not null when debug is in MainMethod().

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using LibW;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AllInOne
{
[OperationContract]
public void DoWork()
{
    // Add your operation implementation here
    return;
}
[DataMember]
private List<LibW.IWeather> returner = new List<LibW.IWeather>();
/// <summary>
/// method set connection to google and get xml document weather for there
/// </summary>
/// <param name="city">city for which find weather</param>
/// <param name="lang">lang of text</param>
/// <returns>return either "finish if all successful or Exception msg or errors with city finding and error with connection</returns>
[OperationContract]
public string MainMethod(string city, string lang)
{
    //check connection
    Ping p = new Ping();
    PingReply pr = p.Send(@"google.com");
    IPStatus status = pr.Status;
    if (status != IPStatus.Success)
        return "Error with Connection";
    //try tp get xml weather
    try
    {
        XElement el;
        HttpWebRequest req =
            (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + city + "&hl=" + lang);
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
        {
            el = XElement.Load(streamreader);
        }
        int addv = 0;
        var v = from c in el.Elements()
                select c;

                    //I get here data from XML(condition,temperature and etc.)

        return "finish";
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return exc.Message;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// return list of weather fot 4 days
/// </summary>
/// <returns>list</returns>
[OperationContract]
public List<IWeather> Final()
{
    return this.returner;
}
}
```

Comment: When you say `returner` is `null`, do you really mean `null` or do you mean it's an empty `List<>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service is comprised of two separate operations and uses a member variable on the service class to attempt to store state between calls. You also don't specify any explicit [`ServiceBehaviorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554644.aspx) on your service class which means the default [`InstanceContextMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) is going to be `PerSession`. However, I'm guessing you are not actually using sessions right now, so you're basically ending up with `PerCall` behavior.

So, what's happening is the call comes in for `MainMethod`, that gets a new instance of the `AllInOne` service class, it executes, fills out the `returner` field, but now that instance is done and ready to be GC'd. The next call to `Final` gets a whole new instance of the `AllInOne` class, so the `returner` field is never going to have been set and, thus, is null.

You either need to use `InstanceContextMode` of `Single` if you want one instance for all your clients (maybe you only have one, don't know) *or* you need to actually enable sessions for the service and make sure your clients are also using sessions properly. Details on how to use sessions are available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx).

Comment: Yes,I've got only one client.

Comment: Ok, well also keep in mind once you make it singleton it's going to retain that value until the host shuts down (IIS app pool, windows service, whatever you're running it in). So you need to make sure the client is always calling MainMethod when they want to force the value to update. Honestly you should change your API design, returning "finished" or an error message is not how web services should work. If there is an error you should throw a FaultException with the error message in it. If you did this you could just return the List<T> from MainMethod itself and not have any of these issues.

Comment: the problem is that I want to know if it is error of connection or just city or language is incorrect so in full version it returns not only !finish! or !error with connection! but also !wrong city or wrong language!.

Comment: Ok, that's doable with FaultException by returning a distinct FaultCode for each issue. Something like: new FaultException("City is no good.", FaultCode.CreateSenderFaultCode("BadCity", "uri:yournamespace"));

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not persistent between calls to a WCF service, because a new instance of your class is created every time a WCF request is made.  All of your requests need to be independent of one another, or else you need a persistent storage container such as a database.  Or you need to use sessions, as indicated by `@DrewMarsh`.

Comment: Wouldn't `returner` be an empty `List<>` instead of `null` in that case?  I kind of thought the same thing as your answer, but then I thought that the entire class would be re-instantiated for each call.

Comment: I'm assuming OP misused the word `null` meaning there was no data, not necessarily that it was actually `null`.

Comment: That's a good point.  There could be an assumption there by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

When I investigated your code, I feel you seem a bit confused about WCF. First of all, unless you call a operation contract in WCF from a client, it does not work by itself. For instance, when you call method final, it just returns a list.
Also, in the mainmethod, you returned a string, which is finish. "Finish" is not a method call, just a string.